# Avoid losing original resolution when uploading or exporting photos from Picasa

Tags: resolution, picasa, upload

After making changes in Picasa preferences with no change in resolution loss (from say, 800kb original image to 235kb after export or upload), I'm at a dead end.

Comment: Uploading from the Picasa desktop client?

Answer (score 3):

Did you choose the original size option for your uploads?

[image]

I uploaded an image just to check and the original size was listed at 2.5mp on my machine and afterwards it was listed the same in the Picasa web album.

[image]

You can set it to always use the original size under the Tools/Options menu:

[image]